# Similarity in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, similarity

I am trying to implement a similar posts functionality in my rails app for this i have this code in my posts controller

```
@related_Posts = Post
    .where('posts.id != ?', @post.id)
    .where(:post_title=>@post.post_title)
    .where(:category_id=>@post.category).limit(5)
```

this work fine, but I'm wondering if there is a way to consider a post is similar to the other when only 50% of title are similar instead of the full title

Answer (score 1):

Using a full-text search engine like [solr/sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) is probably what you want. It can be configured to find related posts that have similar words in the title field.

Comment: I want only to show related post for a post in the show page like Blogs did

Comment: @userails I think this will do what you want. Also how do you define similarity?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use sql `LIKE` function, in rails (`matches`) it will seems as following:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_not_ids, ->(ids = []) { where.not id: ids }
  scope :by_title_like, ->(title = '') {
    arel_table[:title].matches("%#{title}%")
  }
  scope :by_category_ids, ->(category_ids = []) { 
    where category_id: category_ids
  }
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @related_posts = related_scoping
  end

  private

  def related_scoping
    Post.by_not_ids([@post.id])
        .by_title_like(@post.title)
        .by_category_ids([@post.category_id])
        .limit(5)
  end
end
```